# Using "Select by expression" in processing script context with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, select-by-expression

Is there a way to select features and use them in subsequent algorithms within a processing script context?

I am looking to iteratively `selectbyexpression` a subset of line features in a layer based on geometry lengths, then using the selected lines in the `snapgeometries` processing algorithm.

I can do so in the python console with the following code:

```py
point_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('points')[0]
line_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('lines')[0]
longest_length = max([line.geometry().length() for line in line_layer.getFeatures()])

length = 0
while length < longest_length:
  line_layer.selectbyexpression('$length >= {} and $length < {}'.format(length,length+10))
  thresh = (length+5)/2
  params = {'INPUT':QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(line_layer.id(), True),
        'REFERENCE_LAYER':point_layer,
        'TOLERANCE':thresh,
        'BEHAVIOR':3,
        'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'}
        result = processing.run("native:snapgeometries", params)
  QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(result['OUTPUT'])
  length += 10
```

When I attempt to replicate it in a processing script context with:

```
...
source_line = self.parameterAsSource(parameters, self.IN_LINES, context)
...
source_line.selectByExpression('$length >= {} and $length <= {}'.format(length,length+10))
...
```

I get this error:

> 'QgsProcessingFeatureSource' object has no attribute 'selectByExpression'

Comment: You can set the input layer as a `QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer` and read it as `layer = self.parameterAsVectorLayer(parameters, self.INPUT, context)`. In that way you can use `layer.selectByExpression()` as usual. https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/b6a7a1070329a1f167341e3187781954d28f2f39/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/SelectByExpression.py#L59

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if these example scripts will work exactly the way you want but you are welcome to try them.

The scripts are based on the template found [here](https://anitagraser.com/2018/03/25/processing-script-template-for-qgis3/).

One option is to use the [materialize()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsFeatureSource.html#ab95bcca99b1d5c082ca409da04e280b9) method of `QgsFeatureSource` which returns a `QgsVectorLayer`. Example below:

```py
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QVariant
from qgis.core import (QgsProcessing,
                        QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                        QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource,
                        QgsFeatureRequest,
                        QgsExpression,
                        QgsProject,
                        QgsProcessingUtils)
from qgis import processing
                    
                    
class ExAlgo(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    LINES = 'LINES'
    POINTS = 'POINTS'
    
    final_layers = []
 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
 
    def name(self):
        return "exalgo"
     
    def tr(self, text):
        return QCoreApplication.translate("exalgo", text)
         
    def displayName(self):
        return self.tr("Example script")
 
    def group(self):
        return self.tr("Examples")
 
    def groupId(self):
        return "examples"
 
    def shortHelpString(self):
        return self.tr("Example script with vector layer inputs")
 
    def helpUrl(self):
        return "https://qgis.org"
         
    def createInstance(self):
        return type(self)()
   
    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
            self.LINES,
            self.tr("Input line layer"),
            [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorLine]))
            
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
            self.POINTS,
            self.tr("Input point layer"),
            [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPoint]))
 
    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):

        # retrieve your input file parameter
        source_lines = self.parameterAsSource(parameters, self.LINES, context)
        source_points = self.parameterAsSource(parameters, self.POINTS, context)
        point_layer = source_points.materialize(QgsFeatureRequest())
        longest_length = max([line.geometry().length() for line in source_lines.getFeatures()])
        
        #####################################################################
        l = 0
        while l < longest_length:
            line_layer = source_lines.materialize(
                                QgsFeatureRequest(
                                QgsExpression("$length >= {} and $length < {}".format(l,l+10))))
            thresh = (l+5)/2
            params = {'INPUT':line_layer,
                'REFERENCE_LAYER':point_layer,
                'TOLERANCE':thresh,
                'BEHAVIOR':3,
                'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'}
            result = processing.run("native:snapgeometries",
                                                    params,
                                                    is_child_algorithm=True,
                                                    context=context,
                                                    feedback=feedback)
            self.final_layers.append(QgsProcessingUtils.mapLayerFromString(result['OUTPUT'], context))
            l += 10
        ######################################################################
        
        return {'OUTPUT': result['OUTPUT']}
        
    def postProcessAlgorithm(self, context, feedback):
        for index, layer in enumerate(self.final_layers):
            layer.setName(f'lines_snapped_{index+1}')
            QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
        self.final_layers.clear()
        return {}
```

Or another option is to use `QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer` instead of `QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource` and work directly with `QgsVectorLayer` objects.

Example:

```py
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QVariant
from qgis.core import (QgsProcessing,
                        QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                        QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer,
                        QgsFeatureRequest,
                        QgsExpression,
                        QgsProject,
                        QgsProcessingUtils)
from qgis import processing
                    
                    
class ExAlgo(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    LINES = 'LINES'
    POINTS = 'POINTS'
    
    final_layers = []
 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
    def flags(self):
        return super().flags() | QgsProcessingAlgorithm.FlagNoThreading
 
    def name(self):
        return "exalgo"
     
    def tr(self, text):
        return QCoreApplication.translate("exalgo", text)
         
    def displayName(self):
        return self.tr("Example script")
 
    def group(self):
        return self.tr("Examples")
 
    def groupId(self):
        return "examples"
 
    def shortHelpString(self):
        return self.tr("Example script with vector layer inputs")
 
    def helpUrl(self):
        return "https://qgis.org"
         
    def createInstance(self):
        return type(self)()
   
    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer(
            self.LINES,
            self.tr("Input line layer"),
            [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorLine]))
            
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer(
            self.POINTS,
            self.tr("Input point layer"),
            [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPoint]))
 
    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):

        # retrieve your input file parameter
        line_layer = self.parameterAsVectorLayer(parameters, self.LINES, context)
        point_layer = self.parameterAsVectorLayer(parameters, self.POINTS, context)
        longest_length = max([line.geometry().length() for line in line_layer.getFeatures()])
        
        #####################################################################
        l = 0
        while l < longest_length:
            line_layer.selectByExpression("$length >= {} and $length < {}".format(l,l+10))
            thresh = (l+5)/2
            params = {'INPUT':line_layer,
                'REFERENCE_LAYER':point_layer,
                'TOLERANCE':thresh,
                'BEHAVIOR':3,
                'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'}
            result = processing.run("native:snapgeometries",
                                                    params,
                                                    is_child_algorithm=True,
                                                    context=context,
                                                    feedback=feedback)
            self.final_layers.append(QgsProcessingUtils.mapLayerFromString(result['OUTPUT'], context))
            l += 10
        ######################################################################
        
        return {'OUTPUT': result['OUTPUT']}
        
    def postProcessAlgorithm(self, context, feedback):
        for index, layer in enumerate(self.final_layers):
            layer.setName(f'lines_snapped_{index+1}')
            QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
        self.final_layers.clear()
        return {}
```